# How do I pass a member function to a function that expects a function pointer?

Tags: c++

I am using a library that expects a function pointer for a callback function but I would like to pass a member function to it.

The way to do this seems to be by using `std::bind` and passing the `target()` as a parameter to the function expecting the function pointer, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef void(__stdcall* ClassicFuncPtr)(int a, double b);

void CallMyFunc(ClassicFuncPtr f) {
    f(1, 2.0);
}

class MyClass {
public:
    void Test() {
        function<void(int, double)> f = bind(&MyClass::MemberFunc, this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
        CallMyFunc(*f.target<ClassicFuncPtr>()); // not working, i don't know why...
    }
private:
    void MemberFunc(int a, double b) {
        cout << "a=" << a << ", b=" << b << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    c.Test();
}
```

The `target()` returns a nullpointer.

Comment: Make `MemberFunction` a `static` member function, and pass a pointer to it directly? Unless it's really using other members of the object, because then there's really no way to do it using the information you have provided.

Comment: The `MemberFunction` expects a `this` pointer. How are you going to pass it, even in principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a member function expects a "hidden" first argument that is a `this` pointer. Loosely speaking, a member function

```
void Func(int a, double b);
```

is equivalent to a free function

```
void Func(MyClass* this, int a, double b);
```

There is no way to pass a `this` pointer via `ClassicFuncPtr`, and `std::function` tricks won't help you here. `target()` doesn't do any magic, it just returns a pointer to the stored function *if* types match, and in your code they don't, that's why you get a null pointer. `std::bind` returns a functional object (that stores `this` inside), but a functional object is quite distinct from a function pointer and can't be converted into one.

Given that you can't change the callback type, there is a pretty ugly and fragile work-around that uses a `static` variable to store the value of `this` pointer. It should give you the idea of how to make it work, at least in principle.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void Test() {
        thisPtr = this;
        CallMyFunc(MemberFuncInvoker);
    }

private:
    inline static MyClass* thisPtr;

    static void MemberFuncInvoker(int a, double b) {
        thisPtr->MemberFunc(a, b);
    }

    void MemberFunc(int a, double b) {
        std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << '\n';
    }    
};
```

Note that `static` member functions don't expect a hidden `this` argument and behave like free functions in this respect (due to the absence of `this` argument, you can't access non-`static` data members inside a `static` member function).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v8oMoeqof)

---

Typically, callbacks are accompanied with a `void*`-like parameter that can be used to pass a `this` pointer. For example, the[`EnumWindows` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) from WinAPI has the signature

```
BOOL EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, LPARAM lParam);
```

That `lParam` is passed to a callback

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);
```

Then, inside a free (or `static`) callback function you could do:

```
reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(lParam)->MyMemberFunction(hwnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that.The type of *pointer-to-member-function* is different from *pointer-to-function*. For example:

- It will be `int (*)(int,double)` if an ordinary function.
- It will be `int (MyClass ::*)(int,dobule)` if a non-static member function of class MyClass

Note: In case that it’s a static member function, its type is the same as if it was an ordinary function `int (*)(int,double)`.

In order to make it work somehow with the non-static member function. It also needs `this` pointer. Thus, you can rewrite the function as following

```
typedef void(MyClass::*ClassicFuncPtr)(int a, double b);

void CallMyFunc(MyClass* t, ClassicFuncPtr f) {
    (t->*f)(1, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: OP wrote that they uses a library. Changing a callback type might be impossible then.